# Does quantum logic describe quantum logic gates?

Tags: logic, quantum-computation, quantum-information

From what I've gathered, there are multiple quantum computational logics.  But, I've been having difficulty figuring out whether they subsume quantum logic or how much overlap there may be.  I even had difficulty finding the term quantum computational logics.

So, please do share to what degree quantum logic describes the logic of said gates and/or how it is interrelated with different quantum computational logics.

(If there's anything I can do to improve the quality of the question, please let me know.)